# how does asp.net code behind work?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, code-behind

i am new to ASP.NET development, and i am a little bit curious on the asp.net code behind mechanism.
i know why we use it
but what i would like to know is:

the relation between aspx page and the code behind

who does the linking between these two separate files ?

how does it work?

how an element created in aspx page can be accessed directly from code behind ?

**I mean what happens BEHIND THE SCENES ?**

thanks